# Does Mule CloudHub use Java SE or EE by default?

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I'm uploading an application to CloudHub and getting ClassNotFound errors for javax.validation.ValidatorFactory.  I believe the javax.validation package is found only in EE and not SE, which is available in my localhost environment.  So, is EE not available to CloudHub apps by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mule is not a JavaEE container so it doesn't embed all the JavaEE extensions to the standard JDK.

If you download Mule Standalone EE and look at the JARs in `lib/opt` you'll see what JavaEE JARs are available by default, which include (but is not limited to):

- Activation 1.1
- JMS 1.1
- JTA 1.1

If you need more JARs or different versions, it is up to you to ship them with your app. You may have to use classloader filtering if you want to use a different version of a JAR provided by Mule.

Comment: David, by 'classloader filtering' are you referring to the loader.override options available for the mule-deploy.properties file?  Are there any other options?